# Buttoning garment on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, boneh-soter, makeh-befatish

Is there an  issue in Halacha with buttoning a shirt or other garment you are going to wear overnight? Adjusting it multiple times over Shabbat shouldn’t be an issue, but if for example someone has a shirt they button on Saturday morning and will sleep in overnight would it be an issue with Boneh or Makeh bepatish melacha? Sources for this question if they exist please